# Convert EC2 ssh .pem key to Azure X.509 certificate?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, openssl, azure, x509

Normally I use a `pem` file to login into my ec2 instance via

```
ssh -i key.pem
```

Now, in Azure, their requirement during instance creation is

```
UPLOAD AN SSH KEY OR PROVIDE A PASSWORD FOR AUTHENTICATION
You can upload an X.509 certificate (in .cer or .pem format) or provide your password to      
sign in to a virtual machine.
```

So how to convert the pem to  X.509 certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure documentation discusses this [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/linux-use-ssh-key/). For some reason, they require you to upload your SSH public key encapsulated in a useless self-signed X.509 certificate. Weird.

Comment: link no longer mentions 509   ... why we like inline answers.